# Profile Photo for mutliple users from Azure AD

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am executing a search operation for people search using Microsoft Graph Endpoint - https://graph.microsoft.com/V1.0/users.

The question I have is - I am able to get all the textual data I need, but is there a way to get photo for each returned user in a single call?. If there are 10 users returned in the previous search, executing 10 different operations to get the photos based on each user's id would be a challenge.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't possible to fetch both user's data and photo in a single call since they are different data types (`application/json` vs `image/jpeg`).

Answer (score 2):

Marc is spot on here.  However you should also check out the new batching feature (note this is still in /beta) which would allow you to get up to 5 photos in one request round-trip.  See https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/json_batching.  We'd love to get your feedback on this.

Comment: Excellent point! I wasn't aware that batching would work with images. I would absolutely consider using this, it will certainly reduce the number of requests you need to make.